# GRUB shell appears after rebooting ubuntu, no problem after rebooting windows

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, asus, windows-10, grub-efi

I have a Asus E402SA with the following disk layout:

- 30GB Internal MMC
- 250GB SSD

I installed Windows 10 on the MMC and Ubuntu 16.04 on the SSD (both partitioned with GPT scheme). The EFI partition with Windows and GRUB boot files is located on the MMC.

When I boot Windows, shut down, turn on again, all is well: the GRUB menu comes up and I can choose Ubuntu or Windows.

When I boot Ubuntu, shut down and turn on, the GRUB shell appears without any error message. This keeps happening every time I turn off and on again the PC, until I boot windows again.

The `exit` command brings the menu back, so this is not a problem with GRUB not finding configuration files. Also, if I select the GRUB entry in the BIOS boot manager the shell does not appear and it goes straight to the menu.

I searched on the internet, found nothing similar. What could be causing the problem? Could this be some system service (or systemd itself) fiddling with EFI vars?

### Debugging info

bootinfoscript output: http://www.pasteall.org/125146

Comment: Did you do some edit your partitions recently?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: @CedaEI This is a clean install on a new PC and a new empty hard disk, so yes I had to edit partitions in the process. But I don't think that's the problem, the boot loader is working correctly, except for that quirk.

Comment: @RodSmith I'll run it and post later. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @RodSmith posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration puts the GRUB binary (`/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`) on the MMC (`/dev/mmcblk0`) and the GRUB configuration file (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) on the SSD (`/dev/sda`). My ***GUESS*** (let me emphasize again: ***GUESS***) is that Ubuntu is somehow doing something to make the SSD invisible to the firmware when the system reboots, but that Windows is not doing this.

You can test this hypothesis by installing an EFI shell binary (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Obtaining_UEFI_Shell) for pointers to some binaries), configuring GRUB to provide an option to launch it (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277373/is-it-possible-to-use-grub-to-run-an-efi-binary) for information on launching generic EFI binaries from GRUB), and launching the EFI shell both in conditions when the problem occurs and when it doesn't. If my hypothesis is correct, the SSD should show up in the device list when you do a cold boot but not when you reboot from Ubuntu. Unfortunately, the device list often scrolls off the top of the screen before you can read it. Putting a small FAT filesystem on the SSD will help you, since you can then check whether it's present or not. (It will show up as `fs0:`, `fs1:`, or some other filesystem device if it's visible.)

***IF*** I'm right, several solutions or workarounds occur to me:

- When using Ubuntu, shut down and restart rather than reboot. Presumably this is what you're doing now.
- Repartition your devices so that you have a small (~500-1000 MiB) `/boot` partition on the MMC. You'll need to re-install GRUB once this is done. The result is that your `grub.cfg` file will be on the MMC, and everything should work correctly. This will require some partition-juggling, though, which can be scary if you're not familiar with such things. (Alternatively, you could re-install Ubuntu to have it set up this way from the start.)
- Upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10. Since 16.10 uses a different kernel from 16.04, this *might* change the reboot behavior to work better with your firmware. This is *not* guaranteed to work, though; it's a both a shot in the dark and a long shot. (Once Ubuntu 16.04.2 is released, you could try it, since it will use the same kernel as 16.10.)
- Research the handling of disks at shutdown (or maybe at startup) more, in the hopes of finding a kernel option that will modify whatever system calls are causing problems. For instance, there's the kernel's `reboot=` option (see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/boot-options.txt) for documentation). This approach will take digging around in documentation files and experimenting with your boot loader configuration, and is ***NOT*** guaranteed to produce results.

Good luck!

Comment: First, thank you for the detailed response. Your guess was my first thought, but there's that crazy thing: simply typing exit in the grub shell brings the menu back. Don't know though if quitting the grub shell is causing some kind of firmware reset.


I already know the first workaround does not work, because the problem also happens on cold boot if ubuntu was the last to be run.


Anyway, I solved the problem by moving the whole EFI partition to the SSD. At this point I don't know whether I should accept your answer, or leave the question unsolved.

Comment: I'd missed the fact that typing "exit" brings up the menu. In that case, it's probably a timing issue -- the firmware is taking some time to identify the SSD, and GRUB is trying to access its configuration file before this works. I don't know of a workaround for this in GRUB. You might try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) It might or might not show Ubuntu options when it starts up. If it doesn't, look into the `scan_delay` option in `refind.conf`. Setting it to `1` is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is 5 years old but I spot the same situation:

- UEFI
- two disks: NVME + SSD (boot partition is on NVME) GPT partitioned
- windows 10 installed on NVME
- ubuntu 20.04 installed on SSD

The key information is this one provided by Rob:

> it's probably a timing issue -- the firmware is taking some time to identify the SSD, and GRUB is trying to access its configuration file before this works.

Setting delay in the bios solved the problem. For my HP Desktop it was `Post HotKey Delay` set to 5 sec.